# exp:member:login returns wrong page

Tags: members, login

I have this

```
{exp:member:login_form return="files/browse" form_class="form default"}
        <input type="text" name="username" value="" placeholder="Username">
        <input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" class="btn dark">
    {/exp:member:login_form}
```

But no matter what, when the form is submitted, it returns the page /site/thanks, not what is specified under "return"... i just don't get it??

What gives?

Comment: If you view the source code the page with the rendered form, what is the value of the hidden `RET` input inside the form tags?

Comment: It is <input type="hidden" name="RET" value="-2" />

Comment: Sorry, I had accidentally removed the return, but added it again now. So now it is <input type="hidden" name="RET" value="files/browse" />... but it still returns /site/thanks... I'm baffled...

Comment: No matter what I do now, wheter it's trying to log in, log out etc etc, it always returns site/thanks... what the fu*k is going on here?

Comment: Have you controlled this site from scratch, or have you inherited it from someone else? Any extensions enabled, especially any custom extensions?

Comment: Mystery solved. I noticed that Design > Message Pages >  User Messages had been replaced by a meta refresh to site/thanks.. wouldn't have gone in that direction if it hadn't been for you. Thanks man! Things are working now :)